# DNS resolving to old IP address after one week

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

Our previous AWS account was hacked last week, on 03/30/2019. We've lost access to it, and had to make a new one.

Our domains are registered at registro.br , and we delegate DNS resolution to Route 53 NS servers. When the incident happened, we created the new account, redeclared a hosted zone on Route 53, and changed the delegation config @ registro.br  accordingly.

In spite of this NS server shift, many of our users are still having their DNS's resolved to the IPs of our hacked account every now and then. The wrong behaviour is intermittent - using the same device, users witness their DNS resolution switching between a faulty and a correct one. I suspect this behaviour is caused by some stubborn cache at the route53 level.

Is this expected behaviour? If so, will it eventually go away? When? What could we do on our end to make it go away faster?

**EDIT**

We've gathered  a DNS trace from one our complaining customers: a query for our site's address  wound up being delegated to an AWS DNS server that isn't listed as one of our hosted zone's NS servers. The address isn't present on our registro.br  configuration either. If I issue a 'nslookup pv.kuadro.com.br  ' command on my laptop, I can see that the name gets indeed resolved to the wrong IP.

Comment: Hi, please collect more detail, as some ISP might badly cache the DNS/NS info, so it can be a test to do on the client side, on there side to do a nslookup to be sure what NS are listed for your DNS. Make them told you their ISP too

Comment: @yagmoth555 which windows/linux tools would you recommend to generate this client-side DNS resolution log?

Comment: I would use nslookup -type=soa yourdomain.com, it would list the nameserver for windows, for linux I'm not sure

Comment: I just gathered a DNS trace from one of our complaining customers. Please check the edits I just made.

Comment: there is nice tool in bind-utils - ``dig``. It is available also for windows. you can run it with ``+trace`` option which would traverse the iteration process so you see where it is asking. More importatnt for this is ``NS`` record (more than SOA as SOA doesn't have relation where to ask ;-)). Try this :``dig +trace NS example.com`` (replace example.com with your domain. You will see where what is returned values and where is it asking... Good luck!

Comment: "Is this expected behaviour?" you are not giving enough details. Troubleshooting DNS involves using `dig` and showing exactly which requests you did and what replies you got. You need to use the `@` parameter to clearly specify the nameserver you query, starting troubleshooting first with authoritative nameserver, down from the root, and then recursive ones.

Answer (score 1):

It can take up 48 hours for the DNS to propagate correctly globally.

I seen in a nslookup soa that the TTL is 1 day, as such the DNS server could cache the value for a day, thus a 1 day delay can be seen there.

Contact registro.br if the change is over 48 hours done in the past, as it would mean the update you did, to change NameServer, didn't worked, as on my side I still see the AWS server in the NS'S field. It could be a technical problem on their side, like the zone is not ok, but it's in their hands at this moment.

Comment: "It can take up 48 hours for the DNS to propagate correctly globally. " This is far more complicated than that. They are no hard rule, and it is not really a propagation (even if everyone says so) because the updates do not flow from top to bottom, it is the end resolvers that will after some time redo the query and update their local cache.